# JSF Required=Yes not working inside a datatable?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, validation, customvalidator, requiredfieldvalidator

I searched everywhere but could not find a solution to this. I am trying to used 
required=yes to validate whether a value is present or not. I am using it inside inputtext.
The problem is it does not work inside a datatable. If I put the text box outside the datatable it works. I am using JSF 1.7 so I don't have the validateRequired tag from JSF 2.0.

I even used a validator class but it is still not working. Does anyone know why does required=yes or validator='validationClass' inside a inputtext inside a datatable is not working.

I appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the proper attribute values of the `required` attribute are the boolean values `true` or `false`, not a string value of `Yes`. It's an attribute which accepts a boolean expression.

The following are proper usage examples:

```html
<h:inputText required="true" />
<h:inputText required="#{bean.booleanValue}" />
<h:inputText required="#{bean.stringValue == 'Yes'}" />
```

As to the problem that it doesn't work inside a `<h:dataTable>`, that can happen when the datamodel is not been preserved properly (the datamodel is whatever the table retrieves in its `value` attribute). That can in turn happen when the managed bean is request scoped and doesn't prepare the datamodel during its (post)construction which causes that the datamodel is `null` or empty while JSF is about to gather, convert and validate the submitted values.

You need to ensure that the datamodel is exactly the same during the apply request values phase of the form submit request as it was during the render response phase of the initial request to display the form with the table. An easy quick test is to put the bean in the session scope. If that fixes the problem, then you definitely need to rewrite the datamodel preserving logic. You could also use Tomahawk's `<t:saveState>` or `<t:dataTable preserveDataModel="true">` to store the datamodel in the view scope (like as JSF2's new view scope is doing).

Finally, JSF 1.7 doesn't exist. Perhaps you mean JSF 1.2?

Comment: I apologize for the version and the request boolean. In fact, our bean is in session scope. I think I got what you are saying but the bean is in session scope and it is still not working. Thanks for the response. If you can think any other things that is affecting the validation let me know as I am not very familiar with JSF.

Comment: To be sure, the table with the input is inside a `<h:form>`, right? And you don't do the data loading job in the getter method of the datatable value, right?

Comment: Yes, it is under form. I forgot to mention that I am using icefaces 1.7. So it is under <ice:form><ice:panelGroup><ice:panelGrid><ice:dataTable> . I don't it is something with icefaces but a task as simple as this should not have been an issue?

Comment: well thanks for the comments I had there were some mistakes in the ids. I was using the same id for form and datatable.